# Catch multiple xhr responses on multiple page.click (without page reload or change)

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await, puppeteer

```
        page.on('response', response => {
           // allow only XHR
           if ('xhr' !== response.request().resourceType()){

               return ;
           }

           console.log(response.url());
        });

    await page.click('span#first');
    await page.click('span#second');
    await page.click('span#third');
```

As result of the example above, just ajax requests corresponding to the span#first are caught by page.on . The span#second and span#third are not caught. Usage of page.waitForNavigation seems have no effect.